# glTexImage2D Invalid Enumerant

Tags: opengl

Any ideas why the following code causes `glGetError()` to return 1280, or invalid enumerant when the OpenGL 3.3 Core Profile is loaded?

```
GLuint texture = 0;
glGenTextures(1, &texture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0,
    GL_RGB,
    textureImage.Width(), textureImage.Height(), 0,
    GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
    textureImage.Bytes()
);
```

It works fine if I don't load the core profile and actually it doesn't seem to fail other than the error code if I use AMD's gDebugger to view the texture's contents.  The texture is a 256 x 256 png that I'm using stb_image.c to load into ram.

Comment: How do you know if that's the code that's causing the invalid enum? Errors are stored until you retrieve them with `glGetError`, so it may have come from anything that came before.

Comment: Sorry, you're absolutely right.  It was glewInit().  I thought I had checked well enough prior, but I was wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`glewInit()` is actually causing the Invalid Enum with the core profile selected.